# In Wcf Integration why there is a restriction to return enum only?

Tags: nservicebus

In Wcf Integration, why there is a restriction to return enum only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that the integration is there to allow you to place messages on the Bus only.  If this is expanded beyond enums, there is a temptation to return more complex data.  This gets you into a Request/Response mode instead of an unidirectional, async messaging mode.  If you need Request/Response then using standard WCF in a standard WCF host may be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if that is the case how can I integrate my legacy component with a service developed using NServiceBus, considering following constraints
• Don’t want to reference NSB dll in legacy component because  that requires upgrading legacy component to .NET4.0
• Want to make a sync call and get response message having some data in

Comment: You can always write the WCF service and host yourself and call into NServiceBus from there.

Comment: The standard implementation is pretty straightforward. You can look into the source code and port it over without enum restriction. BUT usually this is a sign of falling back into RPC style communication. Do you want to query for some data? If you elaborate your problem we can help you design it properly.